# Quizy plugin - using an array for answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the Quizy plugin for creating a custom quiz. http://fillintheblank.quizyplugin.com

The example code on the website looks like this.

```
$('#tutorial-fillblank').quizyFillBlank({
  textItems:['Start of your text', '. text continues ', '. text continues here ', ', ... and here', 'and here it ends.'],
      anItems:['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4', 'Answer5', 'Answer6', 'Answer7' ], 
      anItemsCorrect:[2,1,4,6],
      blockSize:150
});
```

I'm creating the questions and answers by parsing through part of my webpage and 'grabbing' the correct values. This is what my arrays look like.

```
questions = ["question 1", "question 2", "question 3"]
answers = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4", "option 5"]
correct = [0, 3, 4]
```

So, I've tried modifying the example code like this:

```
$('#tutorial-fillblank').quizyFillBlank({
      textItems: questions,
      anItems: answers, 
      anItemsCorrect: correct,
      blockSize:150
});
```

This works for everything except the `anItemsCorrect` item. Quizy doesn't seem to recognize that `correct` is an array. I can't figure out why because it seems to work fine with both the other arrays.

Comment: What's the console output when you put `console.log(anItemsCorrect)` in the code?

Comment: hmm, it can't find the variable `anItemsCorrect` thats odd...

Comment: It would be easier if you showed the whole JS - could be there's some scope problems.